# If I install the same module in sites/all/modules vs sites/example.com/modules, which is used?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I assume that example.com would use its own version of said module, but I don't know. I have the same question regarding themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites/site.com/modules will be used over anything in sites/all/modules.

There's a really good description of how it works on [Acquia:](https://www.acquia.com/blog/power-drupal-multi-site-part-1-code-management)

> **Site-specific modules and themes**
>
> Each site in a multi-site install contains at least a `settings.php` and
>   a `/files` directory. But each multi-site directory can contain modules
>   and themes too - and any modules or themes in those directories will
>   only be available to that site.
>
> For example, imagine I have two sites, example.com and example2.com:
>
> `/sites/all/modules/contrib` contains all of the community contributed modules that I want both sites to share. For example, Views might live there.
>
> `/sites/all/modules/custom` contains all of my custom modules, written specifically for my Drupal installation.
>
> `/sites/example2.com/themes` contains any themes you want to only be available on example2.com.
>
> `/sites/example2.com/modules` contains any modules you want to only be available on example2.com.
>
> When Drupal looks for available themes and modules, it searches in the
>   following order:
>
> `/modules/`
>
> `/profiles/`
>
> `/sites/all/`
>
> `/sites/[sitename]/`
>
> So, when I write my custom theme for example2.com, I can put it into
>   the example2.com multi-site directory:
>
> `/sites/example2.com/themes/chicken`
>
> And the "Chicken" theme will only be available to users of
>   example2.com. Users of example2.com will still have access to all of
>   the themes in /sites/all and /themes, but example.com won't be able to
>   see the "Chicken" theme at all.

Comment: Most excellent! Thanks for that. I read the Drupal docs but not the Acquia ones : )